# create a indexed column in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

Can I create index on a column in the create table command in sqlite?

I tried this command below in sqlite3 in Android shell. It seems to work.

```
sqlite> create table mytest (id integer indexed);
sqlite> .schema
CREATE TABLE mytest (id integer indexed);
```

But, in sqlite's query language specification, specifying a column to be indexed is not supported:

http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html

Did I miss something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

A separate query is needed:

```
CREATE INDEX mytest_id_idx ON mytest(id);
```

Though it sounds like you want to make the `id` column the auto increment primary key?

```
CREATE TABLE mytest(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY);
```

Comment: I just wanted to test whether i can specify a column to be indexed in create table command.
Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Nice to see someone answer with example SQL code rather than bubble diagrams. The diagrams are good but the example code is much easier to understand. There is no need to create an explicit index though on a primary key as there will always be on automatically created for you.