# Do we need to create indexes for sqlite tables in android?

Tags: android, sqlite

As per question..because when I read here

[create a indexed column in sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767571/create-a-indexed-column-in-sqlite)

it seems to say that we need to create indexes manually... but when I read here

http://www.android-app-market.com/sqlite-optimization-in-android-programming-sqlite-optimization-in-android-apps.html

it says indexes are created automatically for every unique column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it says indexes are created automatically for every unique column

No, it says that indexes are created automatically for every `UNIQUE` column. Here, the author is not using capitalization just to be funny. It is referring to the `UNIQUE` keyword that can be applied to a column in a `CREATE TABLE` statement, indicating that all values in the column must be unique compared to all other values in that column.

Most columns in SQL tables are not `UNIQUE`. For some of those, if you are using them in query constraints, you will want to create indexes.

Answer (score 1):

Indexes are automatically created for unique columns, as in columns that cannot have duplicate values, not "every column." You should still create indexes as necessary depending on how you query your data.